# Magento featured product url

Tags: php, magento, url

I am using magento 1.9.1.
I have question regarding how to show uniform product url in entire portal. Traversing product via menu includes category in url but featured product showcase shows product url after domain. I want to make it uniform everywhere. Any suggestions would help me lot. I am new to magento.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like that your work will be done.

```
 $product->getProductUrl() or $product->getUrlPath()
```

Comment: Is this the file where it needs to be changed?app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product.php

Comment: No need to change there. It is default in Magento.

Comment: Where should I make the suggested changes?

Comment: yourtheme/catalog/product/list.phtml. if this is not there then check in base directory.